# Debian driver needed for Intel ICH7M SouthBridge I/O controller

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, sata, libata

I am using a motherboard based on this architecture.

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/navy-pier/embedded-intel-atom-n270-with-mobile-intel-945gse-express-chipset.html

I need the linux driver for Intel® 82801GB I/O Controller Hub (Intel® ICH7). I find only windows drivers for this chipset. Any pointers would be useful.

The actual issue I am facing is as described below.

**Issue:**    Secondary hard disk failure leads to OS Stall..

**Motherboard :**    Quanmax KEMX 2030

**Operating System:** Debian 2.6.32-31

**Our Setup and Application Description:** On the KEMX 2030 motherboard, we connect two HDDs each at SATA 0 and SATA 1. SATA 0 is connected to a HDD(primary) which is loaded with Debian Linux OS. SATA 1 is connected to a HDD(secondary) which does not have any OS but has data storage partitions. Our application runs on the primary HDD and we copy certain critical files from primary to secondary HDD periodically for backup purposes.

**Problem Description:** A faulty secondary HDD results in primary HDD Operating system stalling and freezing. There are two cases that we have witnessed in our field deployments

1. When the secondary HDD has developed bad sectors, whenever a file copy operation is performed from primary to secondary, the primary OS will start throwing DRDY UNC errors in its kernel log. UNC means uncorrectable sectors. The OS is not able to recover from this scenario and the whole system freezes and every application running on the primary HDD will become dead slow because the sata bus is choked.
2. When the sata data cable to the secondary HDD is faulty or of low quality, the primary OS will start throwing DRDY ICRC errors in its kernel log. ICRC means CRC errors in the data transmission. Even in this case, the primary OS freezes.
   Question is that why should the primary OS freeze when the secondary HDD goes bad. Is it because the SATA bus is getting choked? We want the primary HDD not to be affected because of secondary HDD failures.

In order to isolate the problem and we did the following test. With a regular PC motherboard, we connected the same primary and secondary(faulty) drive to simulate the case. On simulating, we found that the linux kernel detects the same DRDY UNC/ICRC errors and in a matter of about 2 minutes, it is able to make the secondary HDD as read only and prevents further damage. The primary OS does not get choked at all. This PC motherboard also had a similar SATA 0 and SATA 1 to which we connected the same HDDs. We could not understand how the PC motherboard handled the scenario better. This test proved that the OS is doing it job on the PC motherboard, but on the KEMX motherboard it does not. Quanmax architecture is as shown in the picture below [image: Arch Diagram].

Do I need a specific I/O controller driver to address this issue?

Further debugging it, we found that irrespective of we connecting the secondary hard disk on SATA 0 or SATA 1 port, linux is able to scan for the secondary hard disk only on SCSI /HOST 0 port. If we do a scan on SCSI/HOST 1, the secondary HDD is not getting detected. Does this mean, the SATA bus is multiplexed into SCSI HOST 0? On the contrary, in the case of regular PC motherboards, we noticed that the scan has to be performed on the respective SCSI/HOST port for the secondary HDD to be detected.

Following is the lspci output on the Quanmax KEMX board.

```
debian:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)

debian:~#
```

Following is the lspci output on the regular PC motherboard.

```
debian:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82562V-2 10/100 Network Connection (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IR (ICH9R) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
```

The difference is that regular PC motherboard has ICH9 family and Quanmax KEMX has ICH7 family.

Following is the kernel log which shows ata_piix version 2.13 is the driver which is being used. Does this version of the driver have a bug?

```
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.569271] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: version 2.13
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.569315] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.569405] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: MAP [ P0 P2 IDE IDE ]
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.569697] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.576892] scsi0 : ata_piix
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.581480] scsi1 : ata_piix
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.584880] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xffa0 irq 14
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.584952] ata2: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xffa8 irq 15
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.756783] ata1.00: ATA-8: ST320LT012-9WS14C, 0001SDM1, max UDMA/133
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.756860] ata1.00: 625142448 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.757445] ata1.01: ATA-8: ST320LT012-9WS14C, 0001SDM1, max UDMA/133
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.757517] ata1.01: 625142448 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.772546] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.789555] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.789846] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST320LT012-9WS14 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.790422] scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST320LT012-9WS14 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.814269] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.814370] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.814658] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.814755] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.814998] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.815068] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.815165] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.815268] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.815339] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.815452] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.816076]  sda:
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.828670]  sdb: sda1 sda2 sda3 < sdb1 sdb2 < sda5 sdb5 sda6 >
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.921110]  sdb6 >
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.922236] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
2013 Nov 21 17:14:19::kernel::[    1.922571] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: What Linux are you using? Which kernel? Is the chipset recognized? Can you see it in the output of `lshw`?

Comment: What doesn't work that makes you think you need a driver ?

Comment: I am using Linux version 2.6.32-5-686 (Debian 2.6.32-31). I need to get to office to get the lshw output. Will do in another 2 hours.

Comment: What are the details of the normal PC motherboard that you used to test ?

Comment: lspci output is added to the description.

Comment: Details of the regular PC motherboard added into the post.

Comment: Can you find another ICH7 motherboard to test with ?

Comment: The problem is not specific to one board. I have tested the same on multiple ICH7 boards and see the same issue.

Comment: Does ata_piix version 2.13 have a bug?

Comment: Does the ICH9 board use ata_piix driver ?

Comment: Yes, the ICH9 also use the same ata_piix 2.13 version of the driver.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think it's to do with the way the ICH7 chipset handles the drives...but that's just my opinion.